# Limiting the number of processors available to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage, performance-testing

I'm working on setting up a test environment, but I need to scale down the hardware we're using for our SQL box, which is running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP 1 and SQL 2008. I'm noticing that MSConfig.exe has options for limiting the number of CPUs available, but I'm not able to find any documentation on how that works on MSDN.

I'm also not seeing any way to change this via command line using the BCDEdit that Microsoft put in.

Anyone know of documentation on this? I'm trying to decide whether limiting the Processor usage at boot would be the best test, or limiting the processors in SQL itself. I'm leaning towards boot time because I'm trying to accurately mimic a lower-power physical box, and if I limit the power at the database level the extra power may show up in other areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an era of multi-core, hyperthreaded CPUs, "Processors" is now an ambiguous term.  Does the processor refer to a threads (from Hyperthreading), cores, or sockets (physical CPUs).

Windows recognises logical processors (LP) as the basic compute platform - giving one LP for each hyperthread within a core, and then multiplied for each core, which is finally multiplied by the number of sockets.

The easiest way in Windows to reduce the LP count is to use the /NUMPROC option. In this example itc creates a maximum number of processors of 8.

> 1. Backup bcdedit /export c:\Backup\bcd.bak
> 2. List of current entries bcdedit /v
> 3. Copy of existing config bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 2008 R2 with NumProc"
>                  The current is a "well known" identifier .  This also returns the Id that is created.  So that can be used directly
> 4. List of entries bcdedit /v
> 5. adding parameter to new entry   To set maximum number of processors
>      bcdedit /set {new_ID} NUMPROC 8
> 6. Changing default entry bcdedit /default {new_ID}

But the danger of this strategy is for example on a 4 core system with HyperThreading enabled then only one processor (socket) is used.  Since the first 8 LPs (0..7) will be hyperthreaded cores on the first processor.  So you are not really emulating an 8 way system - but a 1 way - 4 core system with HyperThreading enabled.

If this doesn't fit your model other options are

- Disable HyperThreading in the BIOS - this reduces the LP count per core so helping distribute the load over cores and sockets.
- Does the System BIOS support reducing the core counter per processor?  If so this will help distribute loads over sockets.
- Building your system within a virtual environment and limiting physical resources from that perspective.

If you are dealing with more than 64 Logical Processors under Windows then that introduces Processor Groups and that add another layer of options.

Comment: This helps, thanks. I know that 16 of my 32 LPs are the result of hyperthreading, so I'll have to disable Hyperthreading via BIOS before limiting the number of LPs further through the boot option. That way I'm actually mimicking the number of cores I want rather than simply removing threads.

Comment: The best answer I've ever seen on disabling LPs on Windows. I actually want to do so to alleviate CPU vulnerability of side channel on an old PC without BIOS
option of disabling HT, but there's no good way to disable HT in Windows systemwide. But if you have a CPU with 2 cores 4 threads, setting `NUMPROC` to 3 (also can be done via msconfig) may be an acceptable compromise between security and performance, or 1 if security is extremely important to you.